# Automatically scrolling to the bottom of a table with UITableViewAutomaticDimension row height? - Swift, iOS 8+

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch

Usually, in a table, the following code can be used to scroll to the bottom automatically:

```
let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: rowCount - 1, inSection: 0)
self.tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, atScrollPosition: .Bottom, animated: true)
```

However, when I set it to use automatic row heights in viewDidLoad() as shown below, the above code only scrolls roughly half way down the table (varies depending on row height and number of rows - it only happens with multiple rows much larger than estimatedRowHeight).

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 50
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

How can I programatically scroll down to the bottom of a table whilst using UITableViewAutomaticDimension?

Comment: I know that it is old, but did you try with contentSize property?

Answer (score 2):

I had a very similar problem when inserting rows to the bottom of a table view with automatic cell sizing, this is the only workaround I could find. It's not pretty but does the job (tested on iOS 8 and 9).
At insertion time:

```
// compute the insertion index as the last one
let insertionIndex = NSIndexPath(forRow: elements.count - 1, inSection: 0)
// delete from the top, insert at the bottom
tableView.beginUpdates()
tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths(deletionsIndexes, withRowAnimation: .Top)
tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([insertionIndex], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
tableView.endUpdates()
// scroll to the last row, position will be wrong
tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(lastIndex, atScrollPosition: .Bottom, animated: false)
// scroll back to the one before, the actual scrolling will be done after inserting the cell
if elements.count > 1 {
     let prevIndex = NSIndexPath(forRow: lastIndex.row - 1, inSection: 0)
     self.tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(prevIndex, atScrollPosition: .Bottom, animated: false)
}
```

as you can see we scroll to the last row just to trigger the row insertion
then scroll back to the row before that (all without animation) to avoid any visible scrolling. 
Then when inserting the cell:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    [...]

    let cell = try configuredCell(forElement: element)
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        let lastIndex = NSIndexPath(forRow: self.elements.count - 1, inSection: 0)
        // when inserting the last element we do the actual animated scrolling
        if indexPath.row == self.elements.count - 1 {
            tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(lastIndex, atScrollPosition: .Bottom, animated: true)
        }
    }
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and adding a delay like this helped me fixing this:

```
let delay = 0.1 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)
let time = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delay))

dispatch_after(time, dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
    let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: rowCount - 1, inSection: 0)
    self.tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, atScrollPosition: .Bottom, animated: true)
})
```

Comment: I would assume that it's an issue with the cells not rendering yet? I'm using 50 rows and even with a 10 second delay, it's still not fully scrolling to the bottom.

Comment: Yes, seems to be rendering timing issue. Did it work for you?

Comment: See my edited comment - I accidentally pressed enter before I finished typing it

Comment: I see. Can you please try implementing `tableView:estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:` and return as close height as possible for the cells you are sure of. You can return `UITableViewAutomaticDimension ` in `else` part covering rest of the cells. It could be bad cell height calculation - just a thought.

Comment: I have a tableview with a label in each cell, some 50 high, some 200+ high. If I use estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath and count the lines in that function, I can get a more accurate number and it does indeed scroll to the bottom, but the code isn't very neat - is this my only option (counting lines, multiplying by font size and adding padding)?

Comment: That is what I think. You may wait for other community folks to respond with their opinions. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

In fact, the reason for this 'misbehavior' of **UITableView** is the row height estimation. When using dynamic cell height, the results of tableView.**contentSize** and for example [tableView **rectForHeaderInSection:** lastSection] are not in sync for items, that have not been shown yet (e.g. item with only estimated layout rects. The section rect for example may be outside the contentSize or somewhere inside, even with no cell inside).

In addition, it seems, that **scollRectToVisible:** will only work with valid rects. So calling it with currently wrong estimations of table view items may just lead to nothing...

My solution to this problem is a ***UITableView category*** which just iterates a few times to scroll to the desired position. So the UITableView has got a chance to calculate the real item layout rects (header, cell, footer). My tests have shown, that in most cases just one loop is needed.

UITableView+LEAScrollToVisible.h

```
//
//  UITableView+LEAScrollToVisible.h
//
//  Copyright © 2016 LaborEtArs. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


/**
 UITableView (LEAScrollToVisible)

 */
@interface UITableView (LEAScrollToVisible)

/*
 scrollSectionHeaderToVisible:withCompletion_LEA:

 */
- (void)scrollSectionHeaderToVisible:(NSInteger)pSectionHeaderIndex
                  withCompletion_LEA:(void (^)(void))pCompletion;

/*
 scrollRowToVisible:withCompletion_LEA:

 */
- (void)scrollRowToVisible:(NSIndexPath *)pRowIndexPath
        withCompletion_LEA:(void (^)(void))pCompletion;

/*
 scrollSectionFooterToVisible:withCompletion_LEA:

 */
- (void)scrollSectionFooterToVisible:(NSInteger)pSectionFooterIndex
                  withCompletion_LEA:(void (^)(void))pCompletion;

@end
```

UITableView+LEAScrollToVisible.m

```
//
//  UITableView+LEAScrollToVisible.m
//
//  Copyright © 2016 LaborEtArs. All rights reserved.
//

#import "UITableView+LEAScrollToVisible.h"


/**
 UITableView (LEAScrollToVisible)

 */
@implementation UITableView (LEAScrollToVisible)

/*
 scrollSectionHeaderToVisible:withCompletion_LEA:

 */
- (void)scrollSectionHeaderToVisible:(NSInteger)pSectionHeaderIndex
                  withCompletion_LEA:(void (^)(void))pCompletion {
    //FLog;
    NSAssert((pSectionHeaderIndex < self.numberOfSections), @"Invalid section header index: %li", (long int)pSectionHeaderIndex);

    // visible part of the scroll view
    CGRect  visibleRect = CGRectMake((self.contentInset.left + self.contentOffset.x),
                                     (self.contentInset.top + self.contentOffset.y),
                                     (CGRectGetWidth(self.frame) - (self.contentInset.left + self.contentInset.right)),
                                     (CGRectGetHeight(self.frame) - (self.contentInset.top + self.contentInset.bottom)));

    // maximum content offset (to avoid to scroll too far)
    CGFloat maxPossibleContentOffset = MAX((-self.contentInset.top),
                                           (self.contentSize.height -
                                            CGRectGetHeight(visibleRect) -
                                            self.contentInset.top));

    // the rect for the header view (maybe just estimated)
    CGRect  sectionHeaderRect = [self rectForHeaderInSection:pSectionHeaderIndex];

    // the theoretical offset to show the header rect topmost in the table view visible area
    CGFloat contentOffsetToBeVisibleAtTop = (CGRectGetMinY(sectionHeaderRect) - self.contentInset.top);

    // the real target offset
    CGFloat targetContentOffsetY = MIN(contentOffsetToBeVisibleAtTop, maxPossibleContentOffset);

    if (0.5 <= fabs(self.contentOffset.y - targetContentOffsetY)) {
        // current offset is different -> move

        // disable user interaction to avoid disturbances
        self.userInteractionEnabled = NO;

        // Scroll to target offset
        [self setContentOffset:CGPointMake(self.contentOffset.x, targetContentOffsetY)
                      animated:YES];

        // Reiterate after waiting for the animation to finalize
        dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.5 * NSEC_PER_SEC)),
                       dispatch_get_main_queue(),
                       ^{
                           // Reenable user interaction
                           self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

                           [self scrollSectionHeaderToVisible:pSectionHeaderIndex
                                           withCompletion_LEA:pCompletion];
                       });

    } else {
        // current offset fits -> execute completion block
        if (pCompletion) {
            pCompletion();
        }
    }
}

/*
 scrollRowToVisible:withCompletion_LEA:

 */
- (void)scrollRowToVisible:(NSIndexPath *)pRowIndexPath
        withCompletion_LEA:(void (^)(void))pCompletion {
    //FLog;
    NSAssert((pRowIndexPath.section < self.numberOfSections), @"Invalid index path: %@", pRowIndexPath);
    NSAssert((pRowIndexPath.row < [self numberOfRowsInSection:pRowIndexPath.section]), @"Invalid index path: %@", pRowIndexPath);

    // visible part of the scroll view
    CGRect  visibleRect = CGRectMake((self.contentInset.left + self.contentOffset.x),
                                     (self.contentInset.top + self.contentOffset.y),
                                     (CGRectGetWidth(self.frame) - (self.contentInset.left + self.contentInset.right)),
                                     (CGRectGetHeight(self.frame) - (self.contentInset.top + self.contentInset.bottom)));

    // maximum content offset (to avoid to scroll too far)
    CGFloat maxPossibleContentOffset = MAX((-self.contentInset.top),
                                           (self.contentSize.height -
                                            CGRectGetHeight(visibleRect) -
                                            self.contentInset.top));

    // the rect for the cell view (maybe just estimated)
    CGRect  cellRect = [self rectForRowAtIndexPath:pRowIndexPath];

    // the theoretical offset to show the row rect topmost in the table view visible area
    CGFloat contentOffsetToBeVisibleAtTop = (CGRectGetMinY(cellRect) - self.contentInset.top);

    // the real target offset
    CGFloat targetContentOffsetY = MIN(contentOffsetToBeVisibleAtTop, maxPossibleContentOffset);

    if (0.5 <= fabs(self.contentOffset.y - targetContentOffsetY)) {
        // current offset is different -> move

        // disable user interaction to avoid disturbances
        self.userInteractionEnabled = NO;

        // Scroll to target offset
        [self setContentOffset:CGPointMake(self.contentOffset.x, targetContentOffsetY)
                      animated:YES];

        // Reiterate after waiting for the animation to finalize
        dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.5 * NSEC_PER_SEC)),
                       dispatch_get_main_queue(),
                       ^{
                           // Reenable user interaction
                           self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

                           [self scrollRowToVisible:pRowIndexPath
                                 withCompletion_LEA:pCompletion];
                       });

    } else {
        // current offset fits -> execute completion block
        if (pCompletion) {
            pCompletion();
        }
    }
}

/*
 scrollSectionFooterToVisible:withCompletion_LEA:

 */
- (void)scrollSectionFooterToVisible:(NSInteger)pSectionFooterIndex
                  withCompletion_LEA:(void (^)(void))pCompletion {
    //FLog;
    NSAssert((pSectionFooterIndex < self.numberOfSections), @"Invalid section footer index: %li", (long int)pSectionFooterIndex);

    // visible part of the scroll view
    CGRect  visibleRect = CGRectMake((self.contentInset.left + self.contentOffset.x),
                                     (self.contentInset.top + self.contentOffset.y),
                                     (CGRectGetWidth(self.frame) - (self.contentInset.left + self.contentInset.right)),
                                     (CGRectGetHeight(self.frame) - (self.contentInset.top + self.contentInset.bottom)));

    // maximum content offset (to avoid to scroll too far)
    CGFloat maxPossibleContentOffset = MAX((-self.contentInset.top),
                                           (self.contentSize.height -
                                            CGRectGetHeight(visibleRect) -
                                            self.contentInset.top));

    // the rect for the footer view (maybe just estimated)
    CGRect  sectionFooterRect = [self rectForFooterInSection:pSectionFooterIndex];

    // the theoretical offset to show the footer rect topmost in the table view visible area
    CGFloat contentOffsetToBeVisibleAtTop = (CGRectGetMinY(sectionFooterRect) - self.contentInset.top);

    // the real target offset
    CGFloat targetContentOffsetY = MIN(contentOffsetToBeVisibleAtTop, maxPossibleContentOffset);

    if (0.5 <= fabs(self.contentOffset.y - targetContentOffsetY)) {
        // current offset is different -> move

        // disable user interaction to avoid disturbances
        self.userInteractionEnabled = NO;

        // Scroll to target offset
        [self setContentOffset:CGPointMake(self.contentOffset.x, targetContentOffsetY)
                      animated:YES];

        // Reiterate after waiting for the animation to finalize
        dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.5 * NSEC_PER_SEC)),
                       dispatch_get_main_queue(),
                       ^{
                           // Reenable user interaction
                           self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

                           [self scrollSectionFooterToVisible:pSectionFooterIndex
                                           withCompletion_LEA:pCompletion];
                       });

    } else {
        // current offset fits -> execute completion block
        if (pCompletion) {
            pCompletion();
        }
    }
}

@end
```