# how to move to bottom of tableview each time when content grows in LynnBubbleTableView framework?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am using [this chat layout from github](https://github.com/Minene/LynnBubbleTableView). In that I am facing this scroll issue. When the content in the tableview grows, the new content must be visible automatically without being scrolled by the user. I don't know how to fix this bug in this framework.

Comment: Although it seems to be broad, logically this could be what are you looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33705371/how-to-scroll-to-the-exact-end-of-the-uitableview

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UITableView , Scroll to bottom on reload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5112346/uitableview-scroll-to-bottom-on-reload)

Comment: I checked out all the above questions, but when I add it , my app gets SIGABRT signal and crashes at the line which i added to move to bottom.

Comment: here the tableview is not of type uitableview. it is of type Lynnbubbletableview. How to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I go through your library.Please add these line of code for scrolling to the last position.

After self.tbBubbleDemo.reloadData():

```
 let lastSectionIndex = self.tbBubbleDemo!.numberOfSections - 1

    // Then grab the number of rows in the last section
    let lastRowIndex = self.tbBubbleDemo!.numberOfRows(inSection: lastSectionIndex) - 1

    // Now just construct the index path
    let pathToLastRow = IndexPath(row: lastRowIndex, section: lastSectionIndex)

    // Make the last row visible
    self.tbBubbleDemo?.scrollToRow(at: pathToLastRow as IndexPath, at: UITableViewScrollPosition.none, animated: true)
```

Comment: I tried it , but SIGABRT is called and my app crashes at line "self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .bottom, animated: true)"

Comment: here the tableview is not of type uitableview. it is of type Lynnbubbletableview. How to add this patch to my code?