# how to go to the top of a tableView on button press

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm using swift, I want to go to the top of a tableView upon a button press, like on twitter pressing the home button will take you to the top of your feed, so far I haven't been able to find a working solution, this is what I've tried :

`tableView.setContentOffset(.zero, animated: true)`

`tableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: -tableView.contentInset.top), animated: true)`

```
func scrollToTop(){
        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
        tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .top, animated: true)
    }
```

All solutions will only take you to an arbitrary cell, bonus points if you know the solution to do this upon a tab bar button click too

Comment: In case you didn't know, tapping the status bar on iOS typically scrolls to the top of the list on screen.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to scroll to the exact end of the UITableView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33705371/how-to-scroll-to-the-exact-end-of-the-uitableview)

Answer (score 2):

First off, I like your username.

Next, what's the problem again with the solution you posted? They're correct, and it seems there's no better way to do it with `UITableView` or `UICollectionView` other than `scrollTo...` built-in function. And setting `offset` for `UIScrollView`.

For the handling of tap on the tab bar, one thing you can do is to subclass the `UITabBarController`, and conform to its protocol, and implement `UITabBarControllerDelegate` desired methods, like:

`func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {`.

From there you can  handle everything, and from there get the `viewController` object and cast it on to your home class, and scroll the view to the top.

What function I use for this? It's similar to yours, but with a little bit of a condition:

```
func hasRowAtIndexPath(indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return indexPath.section < self.numberOfSections && indexPath.row < self.numberOfRows(inSection: indexPath.section)
}

func scrollToTop(animated: Bool) {
    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
    if self.hasRowAtIndexPath(indexPath: indexPath) {
        self.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .top, animated: animated)
    }
}
```

Also, try to tap the status bar of your app and see where it will take you.

Comment: status bar works, but those solutions I tried would only take you up a few cells, not all the way to the top

Comment: This doesn't scroll to the top if there is a table view header and/or a section header.

Comment: @Stopdownvotingmeplease did you try this? : tableView.scrollRectToVisible(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.width, height: tableView.frame.height), animated: true)

Answer (score 0):

I edited my answer again, no indexPath involved:

```
@IBOutlet weak var myButton: UIButton!

override func viewDidLoad() { 
  super.viewDidLoad
}


@IBAction func button(_ sender: UIButton) { 

  myButton.isSelected = !myButton.isSelected
  tableView.scrollRectToVisible(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.width, height: tableView.frame.height), animated: true) 

}

 override func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    if myButton.isSelected {

        print("SUCCESS 1")


    }
}

override func scrollViewWillEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView,   withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {
    if myButton.isSelected {
        myButton.isSelected = false
        print("SUCCESS 2")

    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't scroll to the top if there is a table view header and/or a section header.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the issue was some of the other logic in the button function was messing with the `scrollToTop()` function, this code works:

```
func scrollToTop(){
        tableView.setContentOffset(.zero, animated: true)
    }

    @IBAction func BlogPressed(_ sender: Any) {

        if(BlogIndicator.alpha == 1.0){
            scrollToTop()
        } else {
            articleRefresh()
            self.articleArray = self.blogArray

            BlogIndicator.alpha = 1.0
            NewsIndicator.alpha = 0.0
            RosterIndicator.alpha = 0.0
            DraftIndicator.alpha = 0.0

            tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
```

But I'm still looking for a solution for going to the top of the table view on when pressing the tab bar button