# Scroll to bottom for Table View after Reload Data

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview, sections

I am trying to scroll my table view to bottom after adding comments and replies. Comments are sections and replies are rows for that particular section but table view doesn't scroll at the exact bottom of the content after API call for adding comment, I have tried every possible solution available on net. Kindly suggest any solution for the same

Comment: Could you share some code for better explanation? What have you tried before?

Comment: Try using `scrollToRow` method

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with simple TableView scroll to bottom using `IndexPath`

```
tblView.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(row: 8, section: 0), at: .bottom, animated: true)
```

Comment: Unfortunately there are no rows for the last section

Comment: So are you showing comments?

Comment: I am showing comments which are sections of UITableView

Comment: What do you have in section? Header?

Comment: Yes UITableViewHeaderFooterView whose height is dynamic

Answer (score 0):

From [Jayraj Vala](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54122856/11077258) answer

You've calculate the `contentSize` of the `tableView` to **scroll** at any particular point Use below code to scroll to bottom of `tableView`.

```
func scrollToBottom()  {
        let point = CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.tableView.contentSize.height + self.tableView.contentInset.bottom - self.tableView.frame.height)
        if point.y >= 0{
            self.tableView.setContentOffset(point, animated: animate)
        }
  }
```

- Use described **func()** when you want to scroll `tableView`.

Comment: May I also add that you should call this **after** you call your `reloadData()` function as otherwise it will have the incorrect `contentSize` calculations

Comment: Thanks very much for the help, but I have tried above code which doesn't solve my issue

Answer (score 0):

As an extension for `UITableView`:

```swift
extension UITableView {

    func scrollToBottom(withAnimation animated: Bool = true)  {
        let rowCount = self.numberOfRows(inSection: self.numberOfSections - 1) - 1
        // This ensures we don't scroll to the bottom if there is no content
        guard rowCount > 0 else { return }

        let point = CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.contentSize.height + self.contentInset.bottom - self.bounds.height)
        // This ensures we don't scroll to the bottom if all the content is small enough to be displayed without a scroll
        guard point.y >= 0 else { return }

        self.setContentOffset(point, animated: animated)
    }
}
```

Be sure to call this after `tableView.reloadData()` otherwise the table view `contentSize` used will be incorrect.

Comment: Unfortunately there are no rows for the last section. I want to navigate to last section

Comment: @UserTech Just remove the `rowCount` check then. The point and scrolling code will work

Comment: Yes I have tried the code `let point = CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.contentSize.height + self.contentInset.bottom - self.bounds.height)
        // This ensures we don't scroll to the bottom if all the content is small enough to be displayed without a scroll
        guard point.y >= 0 else { return }

        self.setContentOffset(point, animated: animated)` but unfortunately it doesn't work for me

Comment: @UserTech instead of `self.setContentOffset(point, animated: animated)` can you try `self.contentOffset = point`?. Also try calling `self.layoutIfNeeded()` after too if it still doesn't work.